# Working themes for phpMyAdmin 5.2 and higher?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I cannot seem to find a working phpMyAdmin Theme for version 5.2, I was hoping for the darkwoolf.

I would also be very glad if anybody know a website with themes besides the official [www.phpmyadmin.net/themes](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/themes) that doesn't offer themes for never version...

Or maybe is there a way to make the older theme work on newer phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just uploaded in https://github.com/phpmyadmin/themes/issues the darkwolfbootstrap theme for phpMyAdmin 5.2 for review and later publication in phpmyadmin.net, if you like you can download the zip and try it, regards

Answer (score 0):

You can also manually change the `theme.json` file.

The `theme.json` is found in the theme's base directory. For this example, within the "`darkwolf/`" folder.

Change:

```json
"supports": ["5.1"]
```

To something like:

```json
"supports": ["5.2"]
```

While this allows phpMyAdmin to use the theme, it does NOT guarantee that the theme is compatible in any way. If you find errors, it's a Good Thing (at this time of writing) to add information to the issues at GitHub, as [@SteppenWolf68](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19362404/steppenwolf68)  has indicated [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72666473/3419130), above.

However, other options are to either create your own theme, or to contribute to the theme via GitHub's code mechanisms.

But best of all is to be patient, to simply use the previous stable release until new themes are released for the current version.